# Why does sites like Etherscan display complete state of transactions?

Tags: ether, etherscan, rinkeby, smart-contract-wallets

I just started learning about Ethereum, found sites like etherscan.io very interesting, but was wondering about few things, please help me understand.

**Question 1**

Why etherscan.io display complete information about the transaction like fromAddress & toAddress. I feel it's a potential risk, or maybe I didn't understand the right way.

[image]

**Question 2**

It also displays the state of the transactions as well like before/after transaction states

[image]

I was checking the transaction on the https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/ like [this](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/bytecode-decompiler?a=0x57c8720e915ab4b794b5553cd0ab62e1fe4b6157), and the above leads me to think, why does it display your old vs new balance, that way I can find any wallets ether balance.

**Question 3**

It does allow you to decompile the smart contract's bytecode, that way anyone can decompile any Smart Contract's bytecode, although this feature is experimental, why it is still a feature eg [link](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/bytecode-decompiler?a=0x57c8720e915ab4b794b5553cd0ab62e1fe4b6157)

[image]

I am just trying to get the understanding in place, thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to add: If you run your own client node, then you can determine all of the above information yourself without needing an explorer like Etherscan. Ethereum is deliberately transparent :-)

Comment: @RichardHorrocks Thanks, what's your take on transaction states, which shows before/update the state of the account, that essentially leads to account balance.

Answer (score 1):

> I just started learning about Ethereum, found sites like etherscan.io veryWhy etherscan.io display complete information about the transaction like fromAddress & toAddress. I feel it's a potential risk, or maybe I didn't understand the right way.

Public blockchain is public and there is no problem disclosing public information. There is no risk.

> why does it display your old vs new balance,

Only EtherScan developers know why they designed the website as it is.